# Rails: Authorization with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, authlogic

I need a very granular authorization system that works seamlessly with [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/tree/master).

I've tried these gems/plugins so far:

- [Lockdown](http://stonean.com/wiki/lockdown)
- [rails`_`authorization`_`plugin](http://code.google.com/p/rails-authorization-plugin/)
- [ACL9](http://github.com/be9/acl9/tree/master)

I've also looked at, but not tried implementing:

- [Padlock](http://github.com/bilson/padlock_authorization/tree/master)

I've searched around for a good tutorial detailing how to set up any of these with Authlogic in a way that makes sense (only the Lockdown doc seems to outline how to set this up with Authlogic), but have come up with next to nothing. The only one of these that made the remotest sense to me was the documentation for Lockdown, but I don't think that package will work for me (from what I understand of it).

What I'd really love is a good tutorial *specifically* about setting one of these authorization solutions up with Authlogic, or else a simple example application where I can see how the code comes together and works.  Can anyone point me to any good step-by-step (and why) resources, or else provide a simple application with one of these authorization solutions set up on top of Authlogic?

Comment: Could you elaborate what exactly didn't make sense while trying to install ACL9 with authlogic?

Comment: Well, for one, I got it setup such that if I tried to access a restricted page, I got a Rails Exceptions ACL9::AccessDenied... but no where in the docs (that I could find) does it tell me how to customize how to handle this exception (specially formatted page? redirect to login page? etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your first sentence. You must mean "authorization that works seamlessly with Authlogic." AuthLogic already is an authentication solution.

I think you might be struggling to find a tutorial that's specific to AuthLogic because there's no reason authorization and authentication need to be tightly coupled to one another.

Authentication answers the question: "Who is the person accessing this page?"
Authorization answers the question: "What permissions does the person accessing this page have?

So the only thing your authorization needs from Authlogic is the current_user() method from your controller. For example, take the tutorial for Acl9 (http://github.com/be9/acl9/tree/master). I believe all you'll need to customize is the :subject_method part (Acl9 calls your active user the 'subject', so :subject_method needs to be set to the name of the method that returns the current user, which is :current_user if you followed the basic AuthLogic docs).

Comment: Yes, I did make a typo. My bad. Corrected.

Answer (score 10):

Yay! As of Nov. 16, 2009, Ryan Bates has finally answered my call with a Railscast devoted to this subject!

[#188 - Declarative Authorization](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization) (with Authlogic)

Thanks, Mr. Bates!