# Multiple "login" portals within a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin

We're looking into migrating an existing application to Rails but I cannot find a good example of an application that supports what we need. We have multiple front-end systems that various users can login to. Each user-type functions completely different but there are relationships between them.

*Example*:
An interior design shop hosts regular events for people to attend. The shop hosts the event but the host of the event is actually a 3rd-party interior designer.

3 user types: Attendees, Presenters, and Store Managers.
Attendees must create an account before accessing the system. Once they do, they can peruse the events, register/unregister, etc.

Presenters must create an account before accessing the system. Once they do, they can make themselves available as a host for various events, see the attendees currently registered for their event, etc.

The Store Managers are the super-users who can manage all aspects of the system.

In essence, while all the user-types are inter-related, there is very little common functionality between them. Are there any resources that can provide a good overview of how a system such as this would be implemented?

Comment: Sounds like a job for Actors / Roles.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look for a gem/plugin that provides 'authorization' functionality? Here are some related questions that might be helpful:

[Rails: Authorization with Authlogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970638/rails-authorization-with-authlogic)

[which is the most popular Ruby on Rails AUTHORIZATION gem/plugin at the moment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895433/which-is-the-most-popular-ruby-on-rails-authorization-gem-plugin-at-the-moment)

Here are 2 railscasts that might be helpful:

http://railscasts.com/tags/26